# Use all PC resources to make intensive calculations

Tags: c

I'm writing in C a little script that will generate random numbers.
When I run it for 60 seconds, it generates only 17 million numbers, and in my PC task manager, I see that it uses almost 0% of the resources.

Can someone please, give me a piece of code or link that allow me to use the full resources of my PC to generate trillions of random numbers in a few seconds? Maybe multi-threaded?

Note: if you know a simple way (no heavy CUDA SDK) to use the Nvidia GPU rather than the CPU, it will be good too!

**EDIT**

Here's my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

    char getRandLetter(void);

int main()
{
    int i,num=0,p=0;
    char randhash[12];

    time_t start,stop;
    start = time(NULL);
   while(1) {
        for(i=0; i<12; i++){
        randhash[i]=getRandLetter();
        }
        num++;
        stop = time(NULL);
        double diff = difftime(stop, start);
        if (diff >= 60) {
            printf("60 seconds passed... NUM=%d", num);
            start = time(NULL);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

char getRandLetter() {
        static int range = 'Z'-'A'+1;
        return rand()%range + 'A';
}
```

Note: i have a killer pc with i7 and a killer geforce :p So i just need to exploit these resources.

Comment: If you're not even taxing your CPU, not yet worth going to CUDA.  Odds are your program is inefficient.  Hard to tell without any code or any specifics on what you've done.

Comment: What kind of "PC"? To get 100% utilization on multi-core CPU's, you need to parallelize...

Comment: I think it is unlikely that you will generate trillions with a typical CPU...

Comment: Don't write them anywhere, I/O slows it drastically down.

Comment: Maybe you should post your program.

Comment: Note that a billion is 10^9 and a trillion is 10^12, so to generate a billion numbers in a second, you need to generate one number every 4 clock cycles if you have a 4 GHz clock in your computer.  That load might be spread over multiple cores, but you need a very tight loop to generate a billion numbers in a second. To generate trillions of numbers in a a few seconds, you are going to need dramatically more resources.  Also note that the I/O cost is going to be substantial. What are you going to do with a trillion random numbers in a few seconds anyway?

Comment: I added my code. I just need the code that allows me to run this code intensively. If i need to change the random generation method for that, please advice :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Generating random numbers should not be CPU bound. Functions that generate random numbers usually make a call to the system kernel, which gets random numbers from physical sources of entropy (the network, keyboard, mouse, etc.). The best you can do with computation is pseudo random numbers.

Effectively, there should be ways to use more of your CPU to generate "random" numbers quicker, but those random numbers wouldn't be as high quality as those plucked from physical sources of entropy (and using those sources doesn't flex the CPU much if at all) because CPUs tend to be quite deterministic (as they should be).

Some additional info on:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation